# PowerShell multiline comment regex works in regex101 but not in pandas or re

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have this regex defined in python:

```
multiline_comment_regex = r'(^[ \t]*<#[^>]*#>[ \t]*[\n]*)'
```

And the testing string:

```
characters = 'asdfasdfñáéíóú\n\r\t  <#somecomment \n\r multiline\t\n\r\t asd#>\nasdf\n  #comment'
```

In regex101.com, the regex works as a charm and matches:

```
'\t  <#somecomment \n\r multiline\t\n\r\t asd#>\n'
```

But, using `pandas`, it doesn't match anything:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'process': [characters, ]})
data['process'].replace({multiline_comment_regex: ''}, regex=True, inplace=True)
```

Neither with `re`:

```
re.match(multiline_comment_regex, characters)
```

What is wrong with the regex?

Thank you!

Comment: Try `multiline_comment_regex = r'(?m)(^[ \t]*<#[^>]*#>[ \t]*[\n]*)'`

Comment: Ok, one more try: `(?m)^\s*<#[^>]*#>\s*`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to account for two things here:

- The `^` matches start of a whole string position, you need to use a multiline flag, and in this case, an inline `(?m)` option looks convenient to use
- The line endings seem to be CRLF here, so you can't just use `\n`, it makes sense to match any whitespaces at the start/end of the pattern.

The following pattern should work:

```
(?m)^(\s*<#[^>]*#>\s*)
```

See a [regex test](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3Fm%29%5E%28%5Cs*%3C%23%5B%5E%3E%5D*%23%3E%5Cs*%29&i=asdfasdf%C3%B1%C3%A1%C3%A9%C3%AD%C3%B3%C3%BA%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20%20%3C%23somecomment%20%0D%0A%0D%0A%20multiline%09%0D%0A%0D%0A%09%20asd%23%3E%0D%0Aasdf%0D%0A%20%20%23comment%0D%0A&r=) in the environment with CRLF line endings.

Comment: FYI: `(?m)^\s*<#[^#]*(?:#(?!>)[^#]*)*#>\s*` is a more precise pattern as `<#[^>]*#>` won't match comments with `#` inside.